# Compatible microSD Card SanDisk

Tags: sd-card, compatibility

Does anyone know if one of these microSD-cards is compatible with the Raspberry Pi model B ?

- SDSQUNC-032G Micro SDHC Ultra Class 10 UHS-I
- SDSQUNC-064G Micro SDXC Ultra Class 10 UHS-I

(The second one is just the bigger version of the first one.)

I've looked up following webpages:

- http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards
- http://www.raspberry-pi.co.uk/2012/06/07/compatible-sd-cards/

but both of them seem to be outdated.

I would appreciate any advice. :-)

Comment: All this stuff about SD Cards is rubbish. Any quality card is OK. Be careful with 64GB as these are formatted exFAT. No problem if installing Raspbian, but not NOOBS.

Comment: Thank you! This might be true. My first SD-card seemed to be a poor quality card - first it worked nicely, few weeks later corruption after every reboot. The NOOBS hint is a very good one! :-) I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Milliways Possibly for most uses; I do have a lot of direct experience (in the hundreds, or maybe thousands at this point, of cards) with certain brands having extremely high failure rates or other consistent issues, on various non-Pi systems, but mostly for unusual uses. They all have their quirks. I will say that SanDisk's base model cards (the black ones) have been 100% compatible and reliable in every situation. Also I've observed that general reliability in almost all brands has improved greatly over the past 5 years or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second card is actually the one I use as my primary card in my Raspberry Pi.  I've never had any problems with it, and have been very happy with its performance.

Comment: Thank you! Now i know wich one I will choose :-) Can you just tell me wich Raspberry model you use (just to be sure)?

Comment: I use a Raspberry Pi 2 B+, but know someone that also uses it in a Raspberry Pi 1 B+.

Comment: Do you think that model B (Pi 1) would work too with this card?

Comment: I would be really surprised if it doesn't work fairly universally among the RPi models considering how well it's worked with the two cases I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

The [Embedded Linux Wiki](http://elinux.org/) maintains a fairly up-to-date [Raspberry Pi SD card compatibility list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards).

The `SDSQUNC-064G-GN6MA` is listed there as being compatible with Raspberry Pi 2 B. There is no difference between Raspberry Pi 1 B and 2 B models concerning SD card compatibility. So yes, it is compatible.

However, this is a [`microSDXC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC) and not a [`microSDHC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC) card, it comes formatted in `exFAT`, **which is governed by a proprietary license.** One will have to reformat it to `FAT32` or copy an image over it. NOOB will not work without reformatting. Once installed, extending the file system will work though.

Comment: Have you really read my question, or why are you just copying the link above and talk about model 2?

Comment: ... and that you just wrote a link already given in the question.

Comment: to reformat a drive as fat32 in Windows, use `format /FS:FAT32 X:`